# Android MVP-Architecture How to make Database Calls in the Model with SQLiteHelper

Tags: android, architecture, mvp

I'm currently working on an Android App and i choosed the MVP-Arhitecture. 
My Problem is right now, that i need to read and write something from the Database in the Model, but therefor you need a reference to the Context and that is in the View. I want to know, how to get the Context from the View to the Model without breaking the MVP-Architecture (if it is possible).

Thx!!!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Something has to create the model and the presenter i.e.:

```
 new MyModel();
 new Presenter();
```

Usually this is the Activity

```
 @Override
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedState) {
      Model model = new MyModel();
      Presenter presenter = new Presenter(model, this); // this being the View
 }
```

If you are using a database inside of your model you want to use a dependency to do this, maybe called `DatabaseReader`

```
 @Override
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedState) {
      DatabaseReader db = new DatabaseReader(this); // this being context
      Model model = new MyModel(db);
      Presenter presenter = new Presenter(model, this); // this being the View
 }
```

Now you have a class called `DatabaseReader` that has a `Context` passed to it through the constructor so you can do "database things", and this class itself is used by the model.

```
 public class DatabaseReader {

     private final Context context;


     public DatabaseReader(Context context) {
         this.context = context;
     }
 }
```

and

```
 public class MyModel implements Model {

     private final DatabaseReader db;

     public MyModel(DatabaseReader db) {
         this.db = db;
     }


 }
```

Comment: This is MVC. MVP should not have any reference to the model from the view

Comment: Perhaps, although view is not mentioned in the answer. Further reading: http://blog.blundellapps.co.uk/the-only-way-to-implement-model-view-presenter/